# Background process not running in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /data

find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix

mkdir output

chmod u+x ./script.sh

ls

(sleep 5; source ./script.sh;) & BACK_PID=$!

nohup python ./watcher.py &

wait $BACK_PID

pkill -P $$

ls

ls ./output
```

I am trying to run **./script.sh** and **python watcher.py** together and I need watcher.py to be running in the background however it is not running at all. I have used various methods such as `disown` even directing output to `/dev/null` but nothing seems to be working and it cant run at the background.

However if I remove `&` it will be running and it will result into a race condition even though there is a wait. This is due to `watcher.py` will not stop unless it is terminated as it is watching the directory and it is stuck there forever if I cant kill the process once `./script.sh` has completed. Any suggestions?

Comment: ./script.sh is able to run in the background it is just python watcher.py that is unable to run in the background currently

Comment: It's probably running and exiting immediately for some reason. Try redirecting input from `</dev/null`, since background processes can't read from the terminal.

Comment: may I know how can i do that?

Comment: `nohup python ./watcher.py </dev/null &` ?